# Visual Studios 2015 Crystal Reports, Cannot add a parameter to a report

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2015

[Create New Parameter form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUj5s.png)
Trying to add a parameter to my crystal report and it won't let me pass this screen, clicking ok does nothing I've tried closing it and restarting it. I can't find anyone else posting about this problem but maybe it's because I don't know how to properly word my problem. If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I found my old installer for the crystal reports and reinstalled it. That seemed to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

This so simple, c this-

1. At first create a parameter Name (**parametertest** or your desire name) Type **String** in Crystal Reports
2. Put any where on your Report
3. Call your that Report this way-

Code-

```
  Private Sub ParameterButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ParameterButton.Click
    Dim filterstring As String = ""

    Dim MyReport As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument = New ParameterPassReport
    MyReport.SetParameterValue("ParameterTest", ParameterTextBox.Text)
    ShowReport(MyReport, filterstring, CrystalReportViewer1)
End Sub
```

Result-

[image: Textbox wise Parameter Pass]